# Не получается создать исполняемый jar файл

Tags: java, javafx, jar, scene-builder, артефакты

Пытаюсь jar файл по данной инструкции:
Если вы работаете в IntellijIDEA, можете воспользоваться встроенным механизмом генерации автономных файлов

Cоздайте артефакт:
File -> Project Structure -> Project Settinfs -> Artifacts ->  + ->javaFX Application -> From module 'Your Module Name'

Справа во вкладке JavaFX задайте:
Application Class: ваш класс с точкой входа - методом main 
Native Bondle: All

Проверьте, что Output directory задана правильно (по умолчанию в папку out\artifacts вашего проекта)

Сбилдите артефакт: 
Build -> Build Artifacts -> 'Ваш артифакт' -> Build

Вылетает ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И, там, где должен сбилдится артефакт образуется следующая ситуация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что название программы на русском языке